# How to use parallax.js only from Materialize

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have included jQuery on top and then `parallax.js` from https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/parallax.js

and then called the script-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

But it's not working and showing below errors on console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cash is not defined and Uncaught TypeError: 
$(...).parallax is not a function
```

I don't want to use full `materialize.js`.
Now how can I use only parallax.js part from materialize.js?

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: @M̨̹̖̱̠̭̠̱̘͌̓ͬͫa̧͔͇̗͖͖͑ͭ͝t̆͗̊ͫt I edited the question and added errors.

Comment: I don't know anything about materialize, but I'd just look for a standalone parallax plugin in this situation. It seems that would be far easier than modifying how materialize.js works which your parallax.js appears to be dependent on. Are there any specific features of this plugin that aren't in others?

Comment: I'm also new to this and I don't have much knowledge about jQuery as well. I know just basics.

Comment: That's understandable, parallax could mean different things depending on what you're looking for but I've used this plugin in the past which is standalone http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/